# php cleaning image tag before submitting to database

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

On my website I have a section where a user can write their bio or put info about themselves. In this section they can post pictures.

I am having a bit of a problem with this though; if the user copy and pastes an image from a site such as Google, the styles that the image had stays with it. Like this one:

```
<img id="irc_mi"  -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #efefef 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #efefef 75%, #efefef), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #efefef 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #efefef 75%, #efefef); -webkit-background-size: 21px; background-size: 21px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648438) 0px 5px 35px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648438) 0px 5px 35px; margin-top: 80px; background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;" src="http://www.fireandice.com/images/P/4060104_a-Small-Cat-Copper-Drip-Wall-Decoration.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="400" />
```

Is there any way to strip the styles off this image tag before I submit it to the database?

I was trying a PHP `preg_replace`, but have been having some trouble with keeping the `src` to the image, because that is the only thing I do not want to replace.

```
$src = '<img src="" width="150" height="226" alt="user image"/>';
preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', $src, $string);
```

Is there any way to keep the original `src`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you allow entering HTML code?

Usually there are two methods that will do the job: Either allow entering a URL, or allow uploading the image.

The first one might be a bad thing because usually you want to host images yourself, and not grab them from anywhere else. Additionally, the other server admin might add anti hotlinking, and these images won't show anymore.

Uploading has it's own class of problems, because without any restriction the user will upload huge, malicious files - and you have to deal with it somehow.

If you really want to sanitize arbitrary HTML, then use http://htmlpurifier.org/ - and don't invent your own scheme.

Comment: I'm really kind of idiot proofing if they copy and paste an image, not code from another website. They do not have access to the html, but in the wysiwyg editor they can copy things from other places. As well they can upload their own images, but again I'm idiot proofing everything.

Comment: As well I would like to create my own instead of using someone else's plug in. I am not trying to hack proof something, just trying to clean image tags.

Comment: I already have disallowed tags and nothing bad does come through. Just because I'm not using one plug in does not mean I'm not protecting my database and website. There are more than one way to skin a cat. My problem is the image tag at the moment, I would just like to make sure they are clean before submitting them to my database. I could just disallow image tags altogether like I am in other places, but I want them to have that bit of freedom in their own bio.

Comment: I posted my code above of what I am trying to do and what I would like to accomplish. I am trying to preg_replace an image while trying to keep the src.